# recording live stream video from tv card using ffmpeg at window

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to record live stream every 1 second from tv card(tv signal) using ffmpeg in window.

first of all, to record live video from tv card, I tried below.

1. First I tried this.

> ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy

then the result is

> "  [dshow @ 000000000024e6fe0] DirectShow video devices
>        [dshow @000000000024e6fe0] "SKYTV HD USB Maxx Video Capture"
>   [dshow @
>   000000000024e6fe0] DirectShow audio devices
>   [dshow @
>   000000000024e6fe0] "Analog Audio In(SKYTV HD USB Ma" "

so I tried

> ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="SKYTV HD USB Maxx Video Capture" -r 20
>   -threads 0 D://test.mkv

But it didn't work. the Error message is

> "[dshow@000000000034d920] Could not run filter
>   video=SKYTV HD USB
>   Maxx Video Capture: Input/output error"

I use the device called 'SKYTV HD USB Maxx Video Capture' for getting tv signal(TV card).

1. The First way deosn't work, I tried different way.

> ffmpeg -y -f vfwcap -i list

then the result is 
"

> [dshow @ 00000000003fd760] Driver 0
>
> [dshow @ 00000000003fd760] Microsoft WDM Image Capture (Win32)
>   [dshow @ 00000000003fd760] Version: 6.1.7601.17514 list: Input/output error

"

so I tried

> ffmpeg -y -f vfwcap -r 25 -i 0 D://out.mp4

then, there is some out.mp4 file in D drive but the file is nothing. 
(I think it is not TV signal)

what should i do to record live video every 1 second from tv card(tv signal) using ffmpeg in window? And How can I set channel at tvcard(Because I want to get tv signal, there are many channels).

Please help..!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: are you trying to get digital or analog TV

Comment: analog TV support has just been added to FFMpeg now, and should be possible, enjoy, or comment here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some tries, I've found this command is working for me:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="HP Webcam" test.mp4
```

of course I was trying to capture video using my laptop's built-in camera, but maybe the same options work for you too, in case you wanted to also specify audio input (from the source I was reading) you should use this command:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="HP Webcam":audio="audio source" test.mp4
```